# org-agenda-custom-commands: how to show only the log

Tags: org-agenda, logging

I'm trying to get the agenda to show a list of everything I have worked on the past week, and only that.

This is close, but it still shows the items that are scheduled, every day since their scheduled dateb:

```
  (add-to-list 'org-agenda-custom-commands
       '("w" "Weekly review" agenda ""
     ((org-agenda-span 8)
      (org-agenda-start-day "-7d")
      (org-agenda-start-with-log-mode '(state clock)))))
```

Using `(org-agenda-skip-function '(org-agenda-skip-entry-if 'todo 'todo))` does remove the scheduled items, but it also removes the started items in which I clocked and the recurring items which are to do at a future date. `(org-agenda-skip-function '(org-agenda-skip-entry-if 'todo '("TODO")))` inversely doesn't remove the started items in which I didn't clock.

It's possible to do exactly what I want interactively, as written in the [emacs manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/org/Agenda-Commands.html) :

> v l or v L or short l (org-agenda-log-mode)
> Toggle Logbook mode. […] When called with two prefix arguments C-u C-u, show only logging information, nothing else. […]

But I can't figure out how to make that happen with `org-agenda-custom-commands`. I had a look in the definition of `org-agenda-log-mode` and it seems that it's setting `org-agenda-show-log` to `'only`, but the help about `org-agenda-show-log` warns to not set it directly and indeed this doesn't end up in log mode at all:

```
  (add-to-list 'org-agenda-custom-commands
       '("w" "Weekly review" agenda ""
     ((org-agenda-span 8)
      (org-agenda-start-day "-7d")
      (org-agenda-start-with-log-mode t)
      (org-agenda-show-log 'only)
      (org-agenda-log-mode-items '(state clock)))))
```

As a chronic procrastinator, the scheduled items significantly clutter the log view. So how could I go about showing only the log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close. If you check the doc of `org-agenda-show-log`(through `C-h v org-agenda-show-log`), you will see you should use `org-agenda-start-with-log-mode`. And here is the menu of choices of `org-agenda-start-with-log-mode`:

```lisp
(defcustom org-agenda-start-with-log-mode nil
  "The initial value of log-mode in a newly created agenda window.
See `org-agenda-log-mode' and `org-agenda-log-mode-items' for further
explanations on the possible values."
  :group 'org-agenda-startup
  :group 'org-agenda-daily/weekly
  :type '(choice (const :tag "Don't show log items" nil)
         (const :tag "Show only log items" only)
         (const :tag "Show all possible log items" clockcheck)
         (repeat :tag "Choose among possible values for `org-agenda-log-mode-items'"
             (choice (const :tag "Show closed log items" closed)
                 (const :tag "Show clocked log items" clock)
                 (const :tag "Show all logged state changes" state)))))
```

Finally, this template works on my side:

```lisp
  (add-to-list 'org-agenda-custom-commands
       '("w" "Weekly review" agenda ""
     ((org-agenda-span 8)
      (org-agenda-start-day "-7d")
      (org-agenda-start-with-log-mode 'only)
      (org-agenda-log-mode-items '(state clock)))))
```